# How to use selectAll with checkedListBox ..?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have  a `checkedListBox`  and a selectAll  `checkBox` .

I want that , if any  of the element  in checkedListBox is unchecked then the selectAll `checkBox` get unchecked (in case it was checked) .

I am working on `Winforms` and using  C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two events, CheckBox Checked changed (for checking all the items) and the CheckedListBox ItemChecked for updating the checkbox:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox1.Checked) return;
    for (int i = 1; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, checkBox1.Checked);

}

private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i).Equals(CheckState.Unchecked){
            checkBox1.Checked=false;
            return;
        }
    }
    checkBox1.Checked=true;
}
```